# Points that follow a 1/R density distribution in an XY grid?

Tags: python, numpy, grid, distribution

I have a XY grid with some gridpoints having certain values assigned to them, in this case, each value means a certain mass, so basically point masses in a grid. I now want to obtain a set of points which follow a density distribution of 1/R, where R is the distance from the center, so R = sqrt(x^2 + y^2). By density distribution, I mean the number of points has to fall off as 1/R. How would I go about coding this?

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-50,50,100)
y = np.linspace(-50,50,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
zeta_a = (25,25)
zeta_b = (-10,5) 
M_a = 150
M_b = 150
```

The zeta_a and zeta_b correspond to 2 point masses having masses of 150 units. I also need to perform follow up calculations using these points, so i'd also like to know how to use a more general format rather than using 'a','b','c' for n-point masses.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not 100% sure I really understand your problem, but you might want to create lists or arrays for **zeta** and **M** like **zeta = [(25,25), (-10,5), ...]** and **M = [150, 150, ...]**, which you can then use as **zeta[n]** and **M[n]** to address the n-th point mass.

Comment: Yeah, my question is how do I generate a list/array for zeta which follows a density distribution of 1/R (distance from the center), the values can be completely arbitrary.

Comment: The (double) integral of `1/R` over the xy-plane is infinite. To be a probability density function (pdf), the integral would have to be equal to 1 -- or at least constant. So I think what you are looking for is impossible. The pdf would have to fall off as `1/R**(2+epsilon)` for some `epsilon > 0` for the pdf to be integrable.

Comment: Right I thought about that, but I just want it to be an approximation, say as long as it doesn't go above 1/R, it doesn't necessarily need to be 1/R. Besides, rather than setting an infinite number of points, couldn't I select a certain finite number, and assign them to follow an approximation of a 1/R distribution? Just the distribution of the points is what I meant by density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question (if not comments are welcomed):

The way to create any given distribution is by interpolating over the inverse of the distribution CDF. This is my function to do it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randdist(PDF, x, n):
    """Create a distribution following PDF(x). PDF and x
    must be of the same length. n is the number of samples."""
    fp = np.random.rand(n,)
    CDF = np.cumsum(PDF)
    return np.interp(fp, CDF, x)
```

Now, in your case we're going to work in polar coordinates with R distributed as 1/r and Theta uniformly distributed:

```
num = 1000   # The number of points
r = np.linspace(-50, 50, 100)
PDF = np.abs(1/r)
PDF = PDF/np.sum(PDF)    # PDF should be normalized
R = randdist(PDF, r, num)
Theta = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(num,)
```

Now let's create the points x and y vectors

```
x = [R[k]*np.cos(Theta[k]) for k in range(num)]
y = [R[k]*np.sin(Theta[k]) for k in range(num)]
```

To plot

```
plot(x,y,'.')
```

[image: plot]

Note that in my answer there is a hard cutoff at r=50. There are ways to overcome this but for now I leave it as it is.

Now you seem to also want to embed the points inside a 2D grid, much like a histogram. You can do that using

```
z, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, [100, 100])
```

Comment: I was also thinking of generating with polar coordinates, but hadn't gotten around to composing an answer.  For the radius I'd suggest using a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) with a shape parameter <= 1, because 1) Python already has it and 2) the shape parameter can be tuned to dial in a better approximation to any real data.

Comment: Wow thanks, this is a start! I do follow the initial part of what you did, still need to familiarise myself with the functions used though, but how would I go about assigning values to these points? Values which indicate the mass, it would be fine if they all had the same value, but I need to assign a value to them...Also, I'm not sure how to use this form of the points in my calculations, for example, right now, in my original post, my points were zeta_a and zeta_b,and I had to perform zeta_min_a_x = X - zeta_a[0], and likewise for the y component, and then again repeat this for b.

Comment: To put it another way, I'd like to be able to use plt.contourf(X,Y,z) to view these points, with z describing them...I'm not sure how to use the histogram to do that

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. The x's and y's of these points are long vectors. You can create a vector m with the same length that will hold the masses. Alternatively you can create a new data structure and assign the coordinates and mass to it.

Comment: What I want to do is simply use these points as the coordinates to put my point masses in, and then perform the calculations with it, like the example one I gave before. SO I'm guessing for this, it would have to be creating a new data structure? Basically, i'd like them to be the coordinates to which I assign a 'z', and then to be able to plot it with contourf, with this, I think I can perform my calculations in a similar manner to the start....Do you think this is possible with creating a new data structure? I am not sure how to do this