# How to create a 1/R distribution of numbers on Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to generate a set of numbers that would follow a 1/R density distribution function, where R is the distance from the origin in polar coordinates. Basically the number of points/concentration of points should fall of as 1/R away from the center. Since I'm still fairly new to Fortran 90, I've managed to make an array of random numbers but taking it to the next step to make it follow 1/R seems tough..The way I create the array of random numbers is below:

```
PROGRAM randomnumbers

REAL::mynum
REAL,DIMENSION(1,10)::matrix


call random_number(matrix)

write(*,*)matrix
END PROGRAM randomnumbers
```

The way I did this in Python is using the inverse CDF and then interpolating but i'm not sure how to go about doing that on Fortran 90. The way it was done in Python is as follows : [Points that follow a 1/R density distribution in an XY grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161872/points-that-follow-a-1-r-density-distribution-in-an-xy-grid/38172416#38172416)

Comment: The cumulative distribution function for 1/R diverges. Do you have a bounded region of radii?

Comment: Yeah, it can be in a bounded region in an X-Y coordinate 2D grid....The size of this region can be any finite number you wish...my desire is to simply generate this kind of distribution and then later control the radii

Comment: You can proceed as you did in Python. You need an interpolation library for the inversion, have a look at https://github.com/jacobwilliams/bspline-fortran

Comment: so whats your cdf look like? you can not mathematically have a 1/r distribution, you must hse some approximation.

Comment: you can have a 1/r distribution if you cut it off at a finite region, let me edit my post to show you the python code to get an idea...I even had a way where you don't interpolate

Comment: you need to both cut off at a finite region and truncate at some region around zero. (which that `linspace` effectively does by avoiding zero ). If you are happy with that python it should translate pretty readily. Can you clarify where you are having trouble?

Comment: Basically I don't know how to translate the libraries I import in python in fortran syntax, things like the np.interp and np.cumsum...I do know how to create a random string of numbers...So apart from that, it appears that I only need to carry out interp and cumsum to achieve what I did in Python